# how to seperate one matrix into showing data for this year and previous

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where my source gives me data for multiple years. In my report data I have 2 parameters- 1 is Brand and 2 is Year. I have made one matrix which has 5 columns in it with a row group. I want to define the column in such a manner where i pass a year to the parameter say 2016, but it automatically returns me data for that and previous year.

I tried using expression in the column group header:

```
=MAX(Parameters!Year.Value) OR MAX(Parameter!Year.Value) - 1
```

and

```
=MAX(Parameters!Year.Value) OR MAX(Parameter!Year.Value) - 1
```

Image of what I currently have:

[image]

What I want to see it as:

[image]

EDIT:

Dataset Sample:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to set a column group by the field year. `Add Group`/ `Parent Group`. Use the year field to create the group.

Comment: column group on any of the fields? but I want to see the data of this year and last year not all the years. Let me try that. At the moment the column group is on Order (maybe because its the first column?) do i apply a parent group to that?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta i added the column group on year field. It still only gives data of the year i pick

Comment: Share a sample of your dataset. I think this can be done easily but I don't know how you can say a row corresponds to a year.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta see question above, i've added the sample. at the moment its only 2016, 2015 for testing, but will grow in size to previous years therefore want it to be generic

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude of your tablix the values you don't need to show.

Go to `Tablix Properties` window / `Filters` tab.

[image]

In expression use something like this:

```
=Switch(
Parameters!Year.Value = Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, "Include",
Parameters!Year.Value-1 = Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, "Include",
true,"Exclude"
)
```

Select Text and Operator select `=`

In Value use this:

```
="Include"
```

If you set Calendar_Year in the column group it will works.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: ok i did that but its still giving the same behavior. I added the code (literally) that you gave in the tablix properties, and had the column group as calendar year. Just to clarify, when i made the matrix, there is already a column group in the first column. Do i make the new column group (calendar year) as its parent and have it cover over all the columns?

Comment: i've added an image above to show what my tablix looks like

Comment: How is year parameter being populated?

Comment: the available value is coming from a dataset called year which is the same column I use in the main dataset with all the other columns i.e. calendar_year

Comment: just to let you know, i also have a filter on my main dataset where i am defining the calendar_year = @paramYear

Comment: I suggest you delete your matrix and recreate everything without filtering the dataset but the data tablix.

Comment: i deleted the matrix and recreated the whole matrix with just the tablix properties set and calendar year column group but no luck. I've now noticed that the only way this worked is if I supply the @param with the available values from the dataset I am using in the tablix. Thats fine but the issue is, it repeats the year in the drop down to as many times as it apears in the dataset. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok so i see something new. I have 4 data sets, first 3 are to pass data to parameter and last is ReportData which populates the matrix columns. When I use filter for report data for brand and market (2 of my parameters) it divides the report in this year and last year with right data. But the instance I give my reportdata dataset the filter of year it just returns the year data of the year i defined in the filter. Why does it behave like this?